# Windows network resource monitor shows active ipv6 connection, but the machine has no ipv6 address

Tags: windows, networking, ipv6

Whilst investigating performance issues on one of our servers (Windows Server 2012) I noticed that the connection with by far the most traffic is to an ipv6 address (`ac19:8020::`).

But according to `ipconfig /all`, and every setting I can see, this machine has no ipv6 address! So how is this even working? Attempting to ping this address results in `PING: transmit failed. General failure`.

There are also `svchost.exe` connections to `ac19:8014::` and `e000:fc::`, although they have almost no traffic. Similar connections also show on another server.

Is there a hidden loopback device on Windows that doesn't show up in `ipconfig`? Even if there is, is this even a valid loopback address?

How can I find out what this address is? Just knowing what interface it is using to talk to it would be helpful at this point.

I should point out that both servers are running in virtual machines on a corporate network. I have no control over the host or the corporate network.

#### Edit

Running `tracert` on any of these addresses results in:

```
  1  Transmit error: code 1231
```

`route print` shows that there is indeed a loopback interface that isn't shown in `ipconfig /all`:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 12...00 50 56 a4 67 4a ......Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
[REDACTED]

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
```

There doesn't appear to be any valid route for `ac19:8020::`, nor is there any IPv6 gateway defined (there is an IPv4 one). If it is being used on loopback, it's a really strange address to be using and I still don't understand how it's even working, given the above routing table.

Comment: Neither  `ac19:80` nor `e000:fc` are the beginning of any allocated prefixes. Are you sure you copied the entire, unobfuscated address? Try providing the entire `ipconfig` output. Where is the next hop for these in your route table?

Comment: Yes those are the full addresses, at least as far as windows will tell me. I agree, they're really strange addresses. I've edited the question with more information.